# Foundation f6 top bar does not seem to work

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I downloaded foundation 6 "essential". Here:  http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/

This download has an index.html file that is an entry into the example page.

I decided I wanted to integrate this module called "f6-top-bar" into the top of the example foundation index.html page:
http://zurb.com/building-blocks/f6-top-bar

To do this I did the following:

I copied the HTML code of "f6-top-bar" here:

http://zurb.com/building-blocks/f6-top-bar

into the index.html file of the foundation 6 download index.html page.

I then copied the CSS of "f6-top-bar" here:

http://zurb.com/building-blocks/f6-top-bar

into the app.css file of the foundation 6 index.html page

The end result was not a responsive menu with a hamburger style icon. It was simply a static unordered list.

What am I doing wrong ?

---

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css/app.css**

```
body {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.title-bar {
  background: #333;
  padding: 0.9rem;
}

.top-bar {
  background: #333;
}

.top-bar ul {
  background: #333;
}

.top-bar ul li {
  background: #333;
}

.top-bar ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-text {
  color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:40em) {
  .menu-text {
    display: none !important;
  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width:40em) {
  .menu:last-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
  }

  .menu:first-child {
    border-left: none;
  }

  .menu li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
  }

}

.dropdown.menu .submenu {
  border: none;
}

.dropdown.menu .is-dropdown-submenu-parent.is-right-arrow > a::after {
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent;
}

.is-drilldown-submenu-parent > a::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}

.js-drilldown-back::before {
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
```

---

End result :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that this requires foundation "complete". Foundation "essential" will not work.